# Change android Locale for only current Activity

Tags: android, forms, locale

Is there a way to change `Locale` in `Android` application only for current `Activity`?

I have a `form` in an `Activity` and I would like to add an option for the user to select in which language he wants to fill the form. So there would be an option to choose the language inside the same activity.

This option should be available at any time and when a new language is selected the form information should be kept. So that it could be done during filling the form.

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("fi");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    config.locale = locale;
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

I have stumbled upon this solution which changes the whole application language but does not change within the current `Activity` unless you reload it. And while reloading the activity, the `form data` is lost.

I suppose I could keep the form information inside a `Bundle` and then reload from there when new language is selected but is there a better way to do it?

**EDIT**

I am displaying the `form` in a `Controller` so chaning `Locale` and then `recreating` the activity really is not an option since it will leave the screen blank for around 1-2 seconds.

Is there any better way to do that? Maybe there is a way to reload only the text fields?

There is one idea that I could think of and that is.. overriding all of the textfields when the language is changed within the application, but is that really a good solution?

```
@OnClick(R.id.btnLocaleEng)
public void onLocaleChangedEng(){
    Locale english = new Locale("en", "US");
    Resources resources = getLocalizedResources(context, english);
    title.setText(resources.getString(R.string.title));
    ...
}

@OnClick(R.id.btnLocaleFi)
public void onLocaleChangedFi(){
    Locale english = new Locale("fi", "FI");
    Resources resources = getLocalizedResources(context, english);
    title.setText(resources.getString(R.string.title));
    ...
}

@NonNull
public Resources getLocalizedResources(Context context, Locale desiredLocale) {
    Configuration conf = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    conf = new Configuration(conf);
    conf.setLocale(desiredLocale);
    Context localizedContext = context.createConfigurationContext(conf);
    return localizedContext.getResources();
}
```

Basically doing this and since I have like 30 fields more I will need to do them all one by one. 
It is hard to believe that there is no other option.

Comment: You will have to update configuration by recreating the activity. On the other hand, the form data not being persistent across config changes, that's something you can handle using `savedInstansteState`. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states

Comment: But with the current soultion it will change the language for the whole application instead of only the selected `Activity`